# Form Processing - All form variables passed through api

Tags: php, forms, curl

I work a lot with leads. I make forms and then take the all of the form variables and run it through an API.

Is there any way to dump all of my form variables to post with curl without writing them all out? It seems inefficient to write them all out. Especially since the form vars are the same name as the API's variables.

The form can not go directly to the API. It just returns some XML, so I run the form vars through the api, then generate a page depending on the result

Thanks.

Comment: Something like [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)? Sorry I'm not really getting what `leads` are.

Comment: more info would probably get you a better answer

Comment: Rewrote the question a little bit.
Yeah, I kind of had a brain fart and didn't think of post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<form method="POST">
```

Instead. This will pass everything to your `$_POST` variable instead of `$_GET` (or it will remain the same if you use `$_REQUEST` however be aware that does clash with `$_COOKIE`!)

Comment: The form can not go directly to the API. It just returns some XML, so I run the form vars through the api, then generate a page depending on the result.

Comment: @DavidKnag This information needs to go in the question, along with any other pertinent data. Waiting for people to answer then dismissing their answer on the basis of some circumstance you should have described in your question just wastes people's time.

Comment: Could you do that processing in javascript before passing it to the API? It would help if you could show us the code/example requests

Comment: Wow I am really out of it today.
What you said was right, I am using post, though. I will just run $_POST through curl.

Comment: @DavidKnag happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 0):

Lot of the ways are available.

1) Use Post method.

```
<form method="POST">
```

for your requirement, get that variable to one new variable into that api, then one time send that variable to another page.

2) Use Session Variable.

```
$_SESSION['views']=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you POST your form do the following

```
 $fields_string = '';

 foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) { 
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
 }
 rtrim($fields_string, '&');

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $API_URL);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The above code will make a string of your POST variables and send it to the API